# Why does NSIndexPath does not work fine in iOS5?

Tags: iphone, nsindexpath

Where ever I used `indexpath` values, the app quits in iOS5. Can anyone say the exact reason for it? I red lot of questions & answers related to this. But still in a confusion.

What is the reason behind this?

What are all the changes that we should do to prevent crashing?

Where can I know these type of code-changes for the upcoming iOS versions?

Update:

Here is the crashed code:

```
MyClass.h

@interface MyClass:UIViewController <......> {
...
NSIndexPath* indexPathOfCell;
...
}

...
...


MyClass.m

....

- (IBAction) someAction: (UIButton *) buttonName {
...
indexPathOfCell = [MyTableView indexPathForCell:swipeCell]; //swipeCell is a UITableViewCell
...
}

...

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
...
[self deleteEntity: indexPathOfCell];
...
}

...
...

- (void)dealloc
{
[indexPathOfCell release];
indexPathOfCell = nil;
...
}
```

Comment: Are you working in the latest Xcode?

Comment: indexpath works fine in IOS5.  The problem is likely due to the way you are using it.  Can you provide a small sample of code that demonstrates the error?

Comment: +1 @AdamDavis,  Post some code where it is crashing

Comment: @ ThE uSeFuL - I am using Xcode 4.1

Comment: How does it crash? Where does it crash? What is in the crash log?

Comment: It is because you have not retained the `NSIndexPath` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the someAction method, you are assigning `NSIndexPath` object to `indexPathOfCell` member. But since it is autoreleased, it will not be available in another method. So you are getting the crash. Instead, do as the following, where I suggest you to retain the variable.

```
- (IBAction) someAction: (UIButton *) buttonName {
  ...
  indexPathOfCell = [[MyTableView indexPathForCell:swipeCell] retain]; //swipeCell is a UITableViewCell
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Can I declare retain property in .h file instead of putting here?

Answer (score 1):

IN IOS 5 NSIndexPath assignment (=) and equality(==) is not working . I have use self before any NSIndexPath object (My Problem has been Solved)

```
Example:-  self.myIndexPath
```

Another way Solving:-

```
FirstIndexPath = (NSIndexPath*) [SecondIndexPath  copy];
```

> Equality works in same way. Like:

```
if([self.mSelectedSubUnitIndex isEqual:SecondIndexPath])
{

}
```

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. Of course the equality and assignment operators work in iOS 5.0. They didn't break fundamental parts of the Objective-C language.